# MySQL can not add row: foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database

I am having issues with inserting data into a table. I have re-created both of these tables several times attempting to solve my issues. The first table, login, holds an id (primary key), username, and password. The second table, userinfo, holds an id (primary key), first name, last name, email, and login$id (foreign key which references login's primary key id). I can insert just fine to the login table, which I always insert first so that the second table can get the first table's id to use as a foreign key. But once I insert data into the userinfo table, I get the 
  **ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constaint fails.**  
  I have no clue why it keeps failing to insert. Any help would be great please and thank you.

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user  | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| passwd| varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstN            | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastN             | varchar(50)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | varchar(125)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| login$id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Here is my code for the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE login(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  passwd VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE userinfo(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  lastN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(125) NOT NULL,
  login$id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (login$id) REFERENCES login(id)
);
```

Comment: Could you please share the `INSERT` queries?

Comment: For the login table: INSERT INTO login (user, passwd) VALUES ('DDan', 'Password1'); For the userinfo table: INSERT INTO userinfo (firstN, lastN, email) VALUES ('Dan', 'Dan', 'email@yahoo.com'); –

Comment: This can probably be because of `login` row not getting persisted before `userinfo` or `userinfo` row having wrong login id. Here's the simple example that works (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16addb/1/0). Could you post the code too (that performs these inserts)?

Comment: I am attempting to populate the tables through a terminal window right now before moving on. The insert into for the userinfo is causing the error no matter where I am coding from (php/terminal). Question though, you are inserting the id for both insert calls and the id for the foreign key, doesn't the auto-increment take care of that?

Comment: @LonelyTwinkly provided an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `INSERT` query for `userinfo` table does not have login id. You can get the last inserted id for `login` by using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` MySQL function and amend the queries like below:

```
INSERT INTO login (user, passwd) VALUES ('DDan', 'Password1');
INSERT INTO userinfo (firstN, lastN, email, login$id) VALUES ('Dan', 'Dan', 'email@yahoo.com', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14798/1/0)**, and here's the documentation for [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

Comment: You beat me to it :)