# I am trying to save depart_id in the table student and it is a foreign key in another table but unfortunately it is giving me an error in php:

Tags: php

I am trying to save `depart_id` in the table `student` and it is a foreign key in another table but unfortunately, it is giving me an error in PHP:

> Can not update or insert: foreign key constraint

Code:

```
$sid_exist='';
```

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
$studid = $_POST['studid'];
$stud_name = $_POST['stud_name'];
$telno = $_POST['telno'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$program=$_POST['program'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$departid=$_POST['departid'];
$sql_exist=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from student where studid='$studid'");

if ($sql_exist) {
  
    header("Location:addStudent.php");
    $sid_exist=$studid." "."Exists";
  
}else{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `student`(`studid`, `stud_name`, `telno`,`email`, `program`,`location`, `gender`,`depart_id`) VALUES ('$studid',' $stud_name ','$telno','$email','$program','$location','$gender','$departid')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result == TRUE) {
    
        header("Location:index.php");
        echo "New record created successfully.";
        
    } else {

        echo "Error:". $sql . "<br>". $conn->error;

    } 
}
```

Comment: this isn't a php problem, it's a mysql issue. There's already an explanation of this which might help you (links below) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312788/mysql-can-not-add-row-foreign-key-constraint-fails and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313895/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-error

Comment: You are open to SQL injections as well. Use prepared statements and paramterize your queries.